# Exercise in Zimmer (Hahn Banach Theorem)

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

This version of Hahn Banach is an exercise (2.1) in Zimmer's book, "Essential results of Functional Analysis".

Let $E$ be a locally convex topological vector space (over $\mathbb{C}$).  $A\subset E$ a closed, convex subset, and $x\in E$, $x\notin A$.  Show that there is some continuous linear $f\in E^\ast$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$Re(f(y))<c<Re(f(x))$$ for all $y\in A$.

There is a hint that says:  Choose a convex, balanced $U\subset E$ (balanced means $r\in \mathbb{C}, |r|\leq 1$ implies $rU\subset U$) such that $(x+U)\cap A =\emptyset$.  Then if $0\in A$, consider the seminorm defined by $A+U/2$.  (Importantly it was proved in an earlier exercise (1.6) that if $W$ is a convex balanced set then it defines a seminorm as $$\|v\|:= inf\{t\in \mathbb{R}: v\in tW\}.$$

The balance property seems to be required for the $\|rv\|=|r|\|v\|$ property of the seminorm.  Convexity for the triangle inequality)

Now I don't really have any idea what Zimmer has in mind here.  First of all $A+U/2$ will not in general be balanced, so how does it give a seminorm?  You could try to "balance" it by multiplying it with the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}$ but how do you keep convexity, or still avoid $x$? Also where would one go from there?  I assume one uses the standard Hahn Banach theorem to find $f\in E^\ast$ with $f(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: Try instead the seminorm defined by $0+\frac{U}{2}$

Comment: @N.S.  Do you mean assume WLOG $x=0$?  ok, but then what $f$ do i choose?

Comment: The standard construction here is to define $f: \mathbb R x \to \mathbb R$ via $f(rx)=r \| x \|$. This definition satisfies $|f(z) | \leq \|z \|$ and by Hahn banach you can extend it to a real valued. Also note that a convex set $W$ is balanced if and only if $0 \in W$.

Comment: For the last comment $\Righatrrow $ follows by setting $r=0$ while $\Leftarrow$ follows by applying the definition of convex to $\{ 0, x \}$.

Comment: @N.S.  wait, the set of nonnegative reals is convex and contains $0$, but its not balanced

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking about real vector spaces, where the definition of balalnced is reduced to $0 \leq r \leq 1$. Try to use $W=\frac{1}{2} U$, and $g(rx)=r\|x \|_W$.